# Поиск id строки в текстовом файле средствами php

Tags: php

Столкнулась с проблемой.

Есть текстовый файл:

```
item({'id':'16', 'title':'Title1', 'date':'2018-10-31 10:16:26', 'content':'Content1'});
item({'id':'18', 'title':'Title2', 'date':'2018-10-31 10:16:42', 'content':'Content2'});
item({'id':'20', 'title':'Title3', 'date':'2018-10-31 10:17:02', 'content':'Content3'});
```

Мне необходимо получить номер строки, в которую входит подстрока "'id':'18'".

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = file_get_contents('file_name.txt');
$str = explode("\n", $data);

foreach($str as $id => $item) { 
    if(strpos($item, "\"'id':'18'\"") !== false) $result = $id+1;
}

echo "Номер строки - ".$result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, код работает, но не с этой регуляркой...

Вот так заработало:

```
$data = file_get_contents('news.js');
$str = explode("\n", $data);

foreach($str as $id => $item) { 
if(strpos($item, '\'id\':\'18\'') !== false) $result = $id+1;
}
echo "Номер строки - ".$result;
```